# Puppet not reflecting changes made in manifest

Tags: puppet

I have a module manifest, let's say it is named as `work.pp`. I added a custom fact `has_work` in `/lib/facter/work.rb`. When I run `puppet agent -t`, and check `facter -p has_work`, the fact has appropriate value. However, in my `work.pp` file, I have a condition like this:

```
if ($has_work)            { $create_file = true }
```

and then based on `$create_file` I have something like this:

```
if ($create_file) {
    file {
      "create file":
        path    => "/path/to/file.ini",
        alias   => "/path/to/file.ini",
        ensure  => file,
        owner   => devops,
        mode    => "0644",
    }
```

However, despite of `$has_work` being true, no file is created on client.

I'm trying to figure out why is it so.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, it would seem that the problem you are facing is specific to puppet rather than Unix/Linux and so may be better asked on stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your syntax is right, or pasted wrong, I recommend using PDK for development. So try the following, in the module, let's call it `example`:

```bsh
$ tree example
├── manifests
│   └── init.pp
└── examples
    └── init.pp
```

```bsh
$ cat manifests/init.pp
class example {
  if ($create_file) {
    file { "/path/to/file.ini":
      alias   => "/path/to/file.ini",
      ensure  => file,
      owner   => "devops",
      mode    => "0644",
    }
  }
}
```

```bsh
$ cat examples/init.pp

include example
```

Test your code with:

```bsh
puppet apply examples/init.pp --noop
```

Also, if you test from Puppet Console UI (in Puppet Enterprise), go and check your graph to see if your resource is being managed.

Know that from a Coding Style point of view, using `if clause` is discouraged as the number of resources being managed are going to be different for different executions. I wonder if that `if` is for:

- I don't want to manage the `.ini` vs
- I don't want to alter/create the `.ini` file as it is already created and may have been modified manually.

If it is the second, you may want to use `file_line` (see [docs](https://doc.wikimedia.org/puppet/puppet_types/file_line.html))

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out and the problem was that the node classifier was dumping a blank a catalog out. I removed the code that was dumping it and now it is working.